# C# Reflection - Set Property Value

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I'm trying to set a property of an object in a class, but the error says `Object does not match target type`.

```
FieldInfo dControl = window.GetType().GetField("dControl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (dControl == null) { Debug.Log ("dControl is null"); return;}

Type typeDC = dControl.FieldType;
PropertyInfo inPreviewMode = typeDC.GetProperty("InPreviewMode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (inPreviewMode == null) { Debug.Log ("dControl.InPreviewMode is null"); return;}

bool value = false;
inPreviewMode.SetValue(dControl, value, null);
```

This is the property I'm trying to access:

```
public class DControl : TimeArea
{
    public bool InPreviewMode
    {
        get
        {
            return dState.IsInPreviewMode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (cutscene != null)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        dState.IsInPreviewMode = value;
    }
    ...
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: why is `dState.IsInPreviewMode = value;` outside the `set`?

Comment: Are you expecting the field to always be an instance of `DControl`? You could just get the field value and cast it. As it is you need to do something like `inPreviewMode.SetValue(dControl.GetValue(window), value, null)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `SetValue` is the *instance* for which to set the value on. ie, it is expecting an instance of `DControl` - your code passes it an instance of `FieldInfo`.

So you might have to get that instance via reflection:

```
DControl ctrl = (DControl)dControl.GetValue(window);
```

And then pass that to the set value

```
inPreviewMode.SetValue(ctrl, value, null);
```